# Why a sleep 300 (5 minutes) can last several hours some time?

Tags: osx, time, sleep, clock

I have a MiniMac with the OSX system.

My script is:

```
while true
  do echo "Sleep 300 seconds = 5 minutes"
  date
  sleep 300
  echo "end of sleep"
  date
done
```

I want it to repeat every 5 minutes; but some time it is suspending for several hours when it does this "sleep 300", here is the result:

```
Sleep 300 seconds = 5 minutes
Fri Nov  8 15:52:49 CET 2013
end of sleep
Fri Nov  8 15:57:49 CET 2013
Sleep 300 seconds = 5 minutes
Fri Nov  8 15:57:49 CET 2013
end of sleep
Fri Nov  8 16:02:49 CET 2013
Sleep 300 seconds = 5 minutes
Fri Nov  8 16:02:49 CET 2013
end of sleep
Fri Nov  8 16:20:59 CET 2013
Sleep 300 seconds = 5 minutes
Fri Nov  8 16:20:59 CET 2013
Sleep 300 seconds = 5 minutes
Fri Nov  8 15:52:49 CET 2013
end of sleep
```

Comment: Don't know why the script might be off and that's an interesting question by itself. However, if you're trying to schedule a script to run on an interval you should use osx's launchd. http://nathangrigg.net/2012/07/schedule-jobs-using-launchd/

Comment: Wait, did time go *backwards* in your last few lines? That'd be the first thing I'd investigate. (Or was that a copy/paste error, since it matches your first timestamp.) The other question is, are you putting the system to sleep? Most likely nothing runs when the system is asleep.

Comment: Do you ever turn off / hibernate the system? The `sleep` then hibernates as well...

Comment: I don't see “several hours”, only about 18 minutes. As others have remarked, your transcript is suspicious: what's that last date about? Please make sure you have a correct transcript. And tell us whether something might have happened such as the system going into standby mode.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a process that either has or is having it's nice level set to a lower level. I'd confirm this with the command:

```
$ ps -eo "%p %y %x %c %n" | less
```

The last column is the nice value and should be 0 in most cases. If it's some other value between -20 (most favorable scheduling) to 19 (least) then something is setting the nice value to this different value.

#### Example

```
$ ps -eo "%p %y %x %c %n"| head -10
  PID TTY          TIME COMMAND          NI
    1 ?        00:00:01 init              0
    2 ?        00:00:00 kthreadd          0
    3 ?        00:00:02 ksoftirqd/0       0
    4 ?        00:00:03 migration/0       -
    5 ?        00:00:00 watchdog/0        -
   15 ?        00:00:06 events/0          0
   19 ?        00:00:00 cpuset            0
   20 ?        00:00:00 khelper           0
   21 ?        00:00:00 netns             0
```

#### Other things

1. Something else that [@derobert's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/977/derobert) pointed out. The time is skewed strangely in some of your output. Might be something is wrong with your clock.

   Specifically this block:

   ```
   Fri Nov  8 16:20:59 CET 2013
   Sleep 300 seconds = 5 minutes
   Fri Nov  8 15:52:49 CET 2013
   end of sleep
   ```

   Looks like we went back in time here!
2. Several people in comments have indicated that your system may have gone to sleep or may have hibernated. This idea would seem to be the best lead, since `sleep` typically uses little CPU time, as indicated by @Gilles in my answer's comments, so would be typically unaffected by the nice level being changed.

Comment: `sleep` doesn't use any CPU time worth mentioning. It wouldn't be affected by the nice level.

Comment: @Gilles - added your info to the answer.